# Polymer 1.0 simultaneous animations

Tags: animation, polymer

I'm using the neon-animation component to animate an element. It works fine, except I'd like to take it a step further.

Here is my animation configuration that works.

```
animationConfig: {
    value: function() {
        return {
            entry: {
                name: 'slide-down-animation',
                node: this.$.target
            },
            exit: {
                name: 'fade-out-animation',
                node: this.$.target
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to combine two animations for both the entry and the exit, but I can't figure out how to do that. Here is an idea of what I thought might work, but didn't:

```
animationConfig: {
    value: function() {
        return {
            entry: {
                name: [ 'slide-down-animation', 'fade-in-animation' ],
                node: this.$.target
            },
            exit: {
                name: [ 'slide-up-animation', 'fade-out-animation' ],
                node: this.$.target
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like this element to both slide and fade at the same time. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the documentation.

Here is the documentation URL: https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-neon-animations#configuration-multiple

Here is a working example:

```
animationConfig: {
    value: function() {
        return {
            entry: [
                {
                    name: 'slide-down-animation',
                    node: this.$.target
                },
                {
                    name: 'fade-in-animation',
                    node: this.$.target
                }
            ],
            exit: [
                {
                    name: 'slide-up-animation',
                    node: this.$.target
                },
                {
                    name: 'fade-out-animation',
                    node: this.$.target
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```